# IList dataset insert to database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, list

I'm getting data set to POST action method's model object like following

[image]

Once I expand above object , it has following properties

[image]

Once I expand above **ListProductFields** IList , it has following properties

[image]

Once I expand above **ListProductFields** IList's object values , `[0]th` value it has following properties and its values

[image]

this is the relevant model class files

```
public class AddNewProduct
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Subsidary_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductFields { get; set; }
}

public partial class AB_ProductTypeCategoryField
{
    public string ProductFieldID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldDiscriptionAr { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public string Field_Value_EN { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_AR { get; set; }
}

public partial class AB_Product_vs_Field
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_EN { get; set; }
}
```

I have database table call `AB_Product_vs_Field` and I want to insert ,

`ProductFieldID` ,`Field_ID` , `Field_Value_EN` from those values from last image

since these are 19 objects have to insert to the `AB_Product_vs_Field` database table I may have to use a loop .

so I created following linq query to insert data to that table

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Add_Product(AddNewProduct product)
    {
        AB_Product_vs_Field insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
            {
                insertproductvalue.Product_ID = product.Product_ID;
                insertproductvalue.Field_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldID;
                insertproductvalue.Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN;
            };

            db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Add(insertproductvalue);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

but I'm getting following error

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I put debug point in front of this line `db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Add(insertproductvalue);` of my code.once this line calling its directing to following section in `App_Browsers.9u0xu-_o.0.cs` file

```
public class ApplicationBrowserCapabilitiesFactory : System.Web.Configuration.BrowserCapabilitiesFactory {

    public override void ConfigureCustomCapabilities(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers, System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browserCaps) {
    }
```

this is the error page I'm getting once this line called

[image]

these are the images of error

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: _See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details_ - we can't see it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke question updated , where I can see that `EntityValidationErrors`,  ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually I cannot notify `EntityValidationErrors` , where should I look at ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added more images , but I cannot understand whats the problems here

Comment: @HenkHolterman that menas do I need add try catch for this ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I cannot find out this `SaveChanges()` method in my project. do need to override that

Comment: I found bug here this is because  `insertproductvalue.Field_ID` getting null here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line in the for loop, then it can keep a record of every tuple

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldID)
```

then my view page appeared like this

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldID)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN,
        new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 })
</div>
```